# How to remove a $ character from a variable's value in Perl?

Tags: perl

Suppose I have a variable which is assigned some string containing `$` character. For example:

```
$a="$192.168.1.1";
```

I have to remove the `$` character using Perl. The text is assigned to the variable implicitly.

How to do it?

```
$v =~ s/\$//;  # this does not work for me :(




$="$192.168.1.1"
$ips =~ substr$ips ,1);
 push (@planets,  $ips
```

Comment: The string "does not works" is not a built-in error message in Perl.

Comment: The bug is you forgot `use strict` and `use warnings`, which would have told you exactly what you did wrong.

Comment: Why would editing `$v` affect `$a`?  Note that `$192` is unlikely to be a defined value (you'd need a regex with 192 or more captures ahead of this code for it to be valid).

Comment: So is that how you are assigning to `$a`, you should do `$a="$192.168.1.1"; print $a; ` if so because you won't get what you expect.

Comment: You've edited your question adding something resembling line noise even more than is usual in Perl.  There is no chance of that code compiling.  It appears that you've not paid any attention to the information given you in either of the two answers.  Please post your complete, 10-line compiling running code (shorter is better), and the output you get from it.

Comment: You shouldn't use the variables `$a` or `$b`. Perl uses these in `sort`. Although their use won't matter to Perl, it might confuse you. Best to use more meaningful names.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is semi-working and working code.

#### Semi-working

```
$ cat x1.pl | so
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $a = "$192.168.1.1";
print "$a\n";
$a =~ s/\$//;
print "$a\n";

$ perl x1.pl | so
Use of uninitialized value $192 in concatenation (.) or string at x1.pl line 5.
.168.1.1
.168.1.1
$
```

#### Working

```
$ cat x2.pl | so
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $a = '$192.168.1.1';
print "$a\n";
$a =~ s/\$//;
print "$a\n";

$ perl x2.pl | so
$192.168.1.1
192.168.1.1
$
```

Always use `use strict;` and `use warnings;` while you're learning Perl (the first twenty or so years are the hardest).

If your code is not working still, you need to show the equivalent SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)) code and the example output, but it should most definitely include `use strict;` and `use warnings;`.

Comment: It might have helped if he had posted code that actually compiled.

Comment: @tchrist: Agreed — the concept of an SSCCE is very valuable, especially in Perl where a very few lines (7 in my code, which is hardly minimal) can do the job.

Answer (score 7):

Firstly, note that you can't use double quotes to assign to `$a` like that, since `$192` will be interpolated and will almost certainly fail.

You should **always** use `use strict;` and `use warnings;` in *any* Perl code.  It would have produced a warning if you actually did attempt that assignment.

So, if your assignment is explicit, use single quotes instead:

```
my $a = '$192.168.1.1';
```

Then, if the `$` is *always* there, just use `substr` - it'll be much faster than using a regular expression.

```
$a = substr($a, 1);
```

If you don't know for certain that the `$` will be there, then the line you used above *does* work, if you apply it to the correct variable:

```
$a =~ s/\$//;
```

or alternatively:

```
$a =~ tr/$//d;
```

Comment: not working for me dnt want to use substr

Comment: @smartboy: If you don't want to use `substr`, say so!

Comment: works for me, and why not use the right function for the job?  Your downvote,  BTW ?

Comment: Your `s///` and `y///` are not equivalent.

Comment: @tchrist they are if there's only zero or one occurrences of `$` in the string.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler because that is also not working

Comment: @Alnitak Which we do not know.

Comment: @smartboy if they're not working for you then you really ought to pick a new alias...  The lines of code above _do_ work!

Comment: @tchrist yes, we do - the OP said `the $ character` - i.e. definite article, singular.  I've already gone beyond the scope of that by allowing for the character not existing at all.

Comment: i am giving this input

Comment: $="$192.168.1.1"
$ips =~ substr$ips ,1);
 push (@planets,  $ips

Comment: that code makes no sense whatsoever.  Read what Jonathan and I have written and go get yourself a good book.  Or better yet several.